# Reescribir una URL en htaccess que viene con parámetros de búsqueda

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Estoy teniendo problemas con una redirección, concretamente esta:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/busqueda.php?busqueda=([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) busqueda.php?web_idioma=$1&busqueda=$2 [L]
```

La URL en cuestión debería ser algo como esto:

```
/es/busqueda.php?busqueda=[lo que busque el usuario]
```

Pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

> The requested URL /xboxone/es/busqueda.php was not found on this
>   server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los parámetros de búsqueda **no están** en una `RewriteRule`. Ahí sólo se compara contra la URL. Para comparar parámetros, hay que usar una `RewriteCond` para comparar contra la variable `%{QUERY_STRING}`.

```py
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)busqueda=([.\w]+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/busqueda\.php$ busqueda.php?web_idioma=$1&busqueda=%1 [NC,L]
```

- La captura del primer grupo de una `RewriteCond` se pasa como `%1` (en vez de `$1`).
- Creo que en vez de los caracteres permitidos en la búsqueda `[-\w]+`, te convendría algo más genérico como `[^&]*` (cualquier cantidad de caracteres que no sean un `&`).

Sin embargo, si no te interesa específicamente validar el parámetro de búsqueda, es suficiente con:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/busqueda\.php$ busqueda.php?web_idioma=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

- Con [`[QSA]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) ([*query string append*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)) le estamos diciendo que agregue los parámetros de búsqueda que ya tenía (agregando sí a `busqueda=...` y cualquier otro que venga en la solicitud).